# How to push content into array from .load() jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
$('#tabPublish').click(function(){

        $('#columnRight').load('/pages/publish/');

        tabArray.push({'linkId': 'tabPublish', 'id': 'columnRight','url': '/pages/publish/',});

        return false;

});
```

I'm trying to push loaded content into an array as as string, but i cant seem to get past this point. I'm trying to do it so when the user clicks a previously loaded tab the code doesnt carry out a .load() again, it just grabs it from the array!

Comment: Don't you want to use `$.ajax`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a callback to `.load()`:

```
$('#columnRight').load('/pages/publish/', function(response) {
    tabArray.push({
        linkId: 'tabPublish', 
        id: 'columnRight',
        url: '/pages/publish/',
        content: response     // assuming you want to do something like this
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call jQuery's **load** method the response string should represent valid HTML that is then appended into the #tabPublish element. By the time the method is done what you've got is a whole bunch of new HTML inside the #tabPublish element.

It seems like what you're trying to do would require $.ajax, not $.load. Am I correct to assume that the object you're passing into the **push** method is what you're expecting the server to return to you perhaps as JSON during the **load** method?

Can you provide an example of a response you expect to get from the server?